# Basic operations returning complex number

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, operator-overloading, complex-numbers

I have written this short and hopefully pretty explanatory code as I encountered an interesting unexpected behaviour while dealing with basic math operations.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

P = namedtuple('P', 'x y')

# euclidean distance with missing parentheses before sqroot
dist = lambda p1, p2:(p1.x-p2.x)**2 + (p1.y-p2.y)**2 ** 0.5
# correct_dist = lambda p1, p2: ((p1.x-p2.x)**2 + (p1.y-p2.y)**2)**0.5

A = P(0, 0)
B = P(1, 1)
AB = dist(A, B)

print(AB, type(AB))  # returns complex?!
print(-1**2 -1**2 **0.5)  # -2.0 (as expected since root not applied to the sum)
```

By the way, this is more for understanding purposes (not for actual use). 
Help me understand this better please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get a complex number because  you have a negative number `-1` raised to an irrational number (`2**0.5`), you have in your `dist` function:

```
(-1)**(2**0.5)
```

you can read more about raising negative numbers to fractional or irrational numbers here:

- [Non-integer powers of negative numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/non-integer-powers-of-negative-numbers)
- [How do you compute negative numbers to fractional powers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers)
- [Raising a Negative to an Irrational Power?](https://web.archive.org/web/20171212193135/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/76619.html)

Answer (score 0):

You missed some parenthesis.

```
(p1.x-p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y-p2.y) ** 2 ** 0.5
```

should be

```
((p1.x-p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y-p2.y) ** 2) ** 0.5
```

Then you get `1.4142135623730951` as expected (and not -2 as you wrote).

The parenthesis are needed because `**` takes higher precedence than `+`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the order of operations that explains this result:

```
>>> 2 ** 2 ** 0.5
2.665144142690225
>>> 2 ** (2 ** 0.5)
2.665144142690225
>>> (2 ** 2) ** 0.5
2.0
```

In your case you get `(0 - 1) ** (2 ** 0.5)`, which is taking a negative number (-1) to an irrational power (`sqrt(2)`), hence the complex output.

We can see:

```
>>> (0 - 1) ** (2 ** 0.5)                                                                                                                                      
(-0.26625534204141565-0.9639025328498773j)
>>> (-1) ** math.sqrt(2)
(-0.26625534204141565-0.9639025328498773j)
```

The exponentiation operator in Python (`**`) groups from *right to left*. From [Python Doc (Expressions)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

> Operators in the same box group left to right (except for exponentiation, which groups from right to left).

Incidentally, your line:

```
print(-1**2 -1**2 **0.5)
```

produces -2 because it is equivalent to:

```
print(-(1**2) - (1 ** (2 ** 0.5)))
```